# Unable to mount windows share with write rights on Debian

Tags: debian, network-share, file-permissions, file-sharing, cifs

I'm unable to mount Windows 2016 Server Core share with write rights on Linux Debian 9.9

[Share settings in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjCJm.png)
("pl:Wszyscy" means "Everyone", Listed users have same permissions as "Everyone")

Share is accesible from my Windows 10 machine, I'm able to read/add/edit/remove files. From linux machine I'm only able to read.

I tried every command listed below in /etc/fstab file, "sudo mount -a" and/or reboot after every change.

```
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs users,rw,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,noperm,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,noperm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,rw,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,users,rw,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
//[addr]/temp /media/temp cifs uid=foxbond,gid=foxbond,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/foxbond/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me 3 days to figure this out...

You need to alter not only "share permissions" but also "security" tab in Windows:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaxt9.png)

Well, it still does not explain why it was working on Windows clients without this change.